# GAE ServletContextListener

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I tried adding a class to my GAE project, to implement the ServletContextListener, however when I add a new class and try to pick from the superclass browser, it doesn't list ServletContextListener as a choice.

I installed Eclipse Juno (Mac 64 Bit), added the GAE plugin, created a GAE project and then added JAX-RS and JAXB jar files manually.

I suspect I may need to add a project facet, such as 'Dynamic Web Module', but whenever I try to do that I get Eclipse errors (null pointer and/or empty user libraries to pick from; I wasn't sure whether I'm meant to create the library but I expected these to be populated after adding JPA / JAXRS facets?).

Have you any pointers on

1) What steps are required to setup Eclipse properly for GAE and JAX-RS / JAXB
2) In addition pulling in Servlet interfaces such as ServletContextListener.
3) Whether earlier versions of Eclipse may solve the Dynamic Web Module problem

Many thanks!
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Because ServletContextListener is an interface, and should be picked from the "Interfaces to Add" button.